# Identify SSL certificate type for apache configuration

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2, openssl

I have SSL certificate files:

- Root2023.crt
- t1.crt
- t1.pem
- t1.pk8

on my apache How can I determine which of these files should be used for SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, and SSLCertificateChainFile or etc,

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html



        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/t1.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/t1.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/t1.pk8
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/Root2023.crt

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I try this config but not work

**UPDATE:**

```
openssl x509 -in t1.pem -text -noout
openssl x509 -in t1.crt -text -noout
has similar output like this:

Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 508... (0x468dc...8)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = rcii
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 14 07:34:00 2023 GMT
            Not After : Feb 14 07:34:00 2026 GMT
        Subject: C = IR, ST = TEH, L = TEH, CN = 172.....
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c4:.....

                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:172.....
            Netscape Comment:
                xca certificate
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        34:bd:9
```

t1.pk8 has pass phrase

```
openssl rsa -in t1.pk8 -text -noout
```

output:

```
Private-Key: (4096 bit, 2 primes)
modulus:
    00:c4:58:f7:e8:bf:ad:f1:f9:aa:33:e7:3c:b3:48:
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    65:a0:6b:08:84:15:c3:55:e7:3b:a0:27:31:e0:74:
prime1:
    00:f2:e1:d3:4e:3f:2e:b3:69:60:cd:8c:8c:78:91:
prime2:
    00:ce:f3:bd:36:44:6e:bd:ae:65:43:62:59:8a:ec:
    af:03
exponent1:
    00:e1:cd:10:a5:ae:17:bc:b4:3b:4a:dd:5f:ba:b7:
    63:0d:e2:0b:18:93:35:8b:3c:df:4b:7e:d5:63:84:
    75
exponent2:
    1f:b9:21:21:f6:6f:7b:48:06:61:c3:eb:b1:ed:fc:
    7d
coefficient:
    37:ff:02:03:bf:37:c0:7f:6f:f8:a6:b1:51:9b:b3:
    fd:cf:fd:49:e3:c5:fb:6d:47:79:a0:0e:2d:99:50:
    eb
```

Comment: try viewing what is inside these files first, with for example "openssl x509 -text -in <<yourfile>" it will display the certificate details (if it's a CA, what is the subjet etc.)

Comment: Also, try viewing them with `cat` or a text editor - that may give you a clue,

Comment: We cannot determine the contents of those files based on the file name. At least `grep "---"` to remove the actual contents and add here what is left.

Comment: I update question with content of cert files and @olivierg but I cant identify type yet

Comment: @garethTheRed cat command show hashed content I want to know apache configurations

Comment: @EsaJokinen I update the question

Comment: content of keys are fake @EsaJokinen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mod_ssl](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html) documentation of each parameter tells what is expected, which more or less answers your question.

#### Private key

> [`SSLCertificateKeyFile` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatekeyfile)
>
> **Description:**  Server PEM-encoded private key file
>
> This directive points to the PEM-encoded private key file for the server, or the key ID through a configured cryptographic token. If the contained private key is encrypted, the pass phrase dialog is forced at startup time.

The `t1.pk8` contains the information required here, but you might want to remove the password so that it won't be prompted every time you restart the Apache:

```
openssl rsa -in /etc/ssl/t1.pk8 -out /etc/ssl/t1.key
```

The resulting file should start with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----`.

As the key file is not protected with a password anymore, you should protect it with file system permissions:

```
chown root:root /etc/ssl/t1.key
chmod 600 /etc/ssl/t1.key
```

#### Certificate chain

> **[`SSLCertificateChainFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) is deprecated**
>
> `SSLCertificateChainFile` became obsolete with version 2.4.8, when `SSLCertificateFile` was extended to also load intermediate CA certificates from the server certificate file.

That should be self-explanatory. Remove this directive from your configuration altogether.

> `SSLCertificateFile` Directive
>
> **Description:**  Server PEM-encoded X.509 certificate data file or token identifier
>
> This directive points to a file with certificate data in PEM format, or the certificate identifier through a configured cryptographic token. If using a PEM file, at minimum, the file must include an end-entity (leaf) certificate. - -
>
> The files may also include intermediate CA certificates, sorted from leaf to root.

If your `t1.crt` is directy signed by the `Root2023.crt` and the `Root2023.crt` is present on the CA store on the clients, you could use `t1.crt` as is.

If you nees any *intermediate* certificates, you should create a combined file having them all from leaf to root. If the `Root2023.crt` happens to be a file containing the intermediate certificate(s) and both are already in PEM format, you could combine them with:

```
cat /etc/ssl/t1.crt /etc/ssl/Root2023.crt > /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem
```

The resulting file should be structured like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Base 64 encoded contents of the leaf certificate.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Base 64 encoded contents of an intermediate certificate.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Followed by the required amount of intermediates (and optionally the CA certificate).

#### Configuration

Now, if these instructions were suitable for your needs & you followed these instructions, your configuration would look like this:

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/t1.key
```